# How to stretch the figure environment across textheight?

Tags: floats, height

When I use the figure environment to set an image as a float in a separate page ([p] specifier), I want to be able to use up the full text height, so that the image and its caption are precisely alligned with text on the adjacent page. I want to have captions at the bottom. This means I need to set the image height to \textheight MINUS the height of the caption that comes after.

I am aware of question: [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page) and the solution offered there works in continuous text, but not in the figure environment.

I was also made aware of question [Height of figure + caption textheight](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47184/height-of-figure-caption-textheight), which comes very close to what I need, except I think that having to set the number of lines in a caption manually is a little awkward, and I am looking for a completely automatic way of computing the caption height.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is a similar question at [Scaling tikzpicture to fit on page with caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73575), perhaps you can modify Heiko's solution to your case.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was able to adapt the solution provided in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/scaling-tikzpicture-to-fit-on-page-with-caption to my purpose. Unfortunately I cannot answer my question here. I'll try later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tikz you could use the "scale" option. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=8mm,>=latex,font=\small]

    \draw[thick,black] circle[radius=1] node[right=1]{normal size};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=8mm,>=latex,font=\small,scale=1.5, every node/.style={transform shape}]

    \draw[thick,black] circle[radius=1] node[right=1]{scaled 1.5 of normal size};

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{this is the caption}


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this only shows how to scale the graphics, but does not calculate by how much.

Comment: I know, I thought to give you a workaround in case you where in a hurry, with a bit of tweaking you could use it for your purpose. Sorry you didn't find it useful.